# Can't run Java on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, server, metaspace

```
$ bin/java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not allocate metaspace: 1073741824 bytes
```

That is what happens if I execute JAVA commands on the Linux server. The problem must not be about PATH as long as I execute it directly by /specifying/the/path

So, what do I do? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://rce-docs.hmdc.harvard.edu/faq/why-do-i-get-java-error-could-not-reserve-enough-space-object-heap

Comment: @user2862981 Thanks! That's at least something. But there are still two extremes:

`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=512m`
Error occurred during initialization of VM
`Could not allocate metaspace: 536870912 bytes`

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=256m
`Error occurred during initialization of VM`
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Comment: You should answer you question, then you could accept the answer.